# Google StreetView/Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

I am trying to overlay a marker on a Google Street View. I am able to get a marker on Google Map, but it's not showing up in the GSV.

https://jsfiddle.net/gnxnm4nt/

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var baltimore = new google.maps.LatLng(39.283024, -76.601765);
  var baltimore1 = new google.maps.LatLng(39.283223, -76.601851);


  var mapOptions = {
    center: baltimore,
    zoom: 14
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var cafeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: baltimore1,
      map: map,
      icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=cafe|FFFF00',
      title: 'Cafe'
  });
  var panoramaOptions = {
    position: baltimore,
    pov: {
      heading: 34,
      pitch: 10
    }
  };
  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);
  map.setStreetView(panorama);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

API Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-overlays
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-embed

Thanks! Please checkout my fiddle for what I've got so far. The should be a marker that appears on the roundabout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the marker to the streetview also (and a different one from the one on the map).

```
var cafeMarker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: baltimore1,
    map: panorama,
    icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=cafe|FFFF00',
    title: 'Cafe'
});
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gnxnm4nt/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var baltimore = new google.maps.LatLng(39.283024, -76.601765);
  var baltimore1 = new google.maps.LatLng(39.283223, -76.601851);


  var mapOptions = {
    center: baltimore,
    zoom: 14
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  var cafeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: baltimore1,
    map: map,
    icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=cafe|FFFF00',
    title: 'Cafe'
  });
  var panoramaOptions = {
    position: baltimore,
    pov: {
      heading: 4,
      pitch: 10
    }
  };
  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);
  var cafeMarker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: baltimore1,
    map: panorama,
    icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=cafe|FFFF00',
    title: 'Cafe'
  });
  map.setStreetView(panorama);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 45%; height: 100%;float:left"></div>
<div id="pano" style="width: 45%; height: 100%;float:left"></div>
```